# ffdec_h264 (video decoder) GstElement not found, libgstffmpeg.so already linked, works fine from command line gcc but not from cmake

Tags: makefile, cmake, h.264, gstreamer, shared-libraries

Some of the lines from a *MyApp.c* file

```
...
GstElement* video_decoder;
video_decoder = gst_element_factory_make ("ffdec_h264", "video_decoder_one");
assert(video_decoder);
...
```

When compiled using command line gcc, it compiles/ runs perfectly fine,

> gcc -o app MyApp.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs 
>   gstreamer-0.10 gstreamer-app-0.10 `

Now I wanted to use cmake(like everybody else!) and hence added some fancy lines, after trying various approaches given on Stack Overflow... [pkg_check_modules()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076820/cmake-pkg-config-library-link-path), [execute_process()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796353/cmake-linking-problem?rq=1) etc. All of them resulted in some errors like

**Error** : assertion 'video_decoder' failed

Question 1 -
What could be the issue here, I have included/ linked the same way as gcc compile command ?

So, I tried to check where `ffdec_h264` actually was and from where normal gcc compile command would have picked it

> $ gst-inspect-0.10 ffdec_h264

resulted in

> Plugin Details:
>
> ```
>       Name:           ffmpeg     
>       Description:    All FFmpeg codecs and formats (local snapshot)  
>       Filename:       /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstffmpeg.so     
>       Version:        0.10.12  
>       License:        LGPL  
>       Source module:  gst-ffmpeg   
>       Binary package: FFmpeg    
>       Origin URL:     http://ffmpeg.org/
> ```

The element was present in **/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstffmpeg.so**

I tried to confirm, hence ran `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10 gstreamer-app-0.10` on command line and got

> `-pthread -I/usr/local/include/gstreamer-0.10 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libxml2  -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lgstapp-0.10 -lgstbase-0.10 -lgstreamer-0.10 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lxml2 -lglib-2.0`

Question 2 - (less priority) 
I don't see the gstffmpeg shared-object being linked from pk-config above, still the compilation using gcc works and code runs fine. How ?

However, the same compilation/run using cmake seems not to be working for me.

Other than normal stuffs, I also have the below line in CMakeLists.txt

```
find_library(GST_FFMPEG_LIBRARIES NAMES gstffmpeg PATHS /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/)
```

and then linked it, refer [find_library()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857000/link-libraries-using-cmake-what-is-the-exact-way-what-should-we-use-find-libra)

Question 3-
Now that I have linked the exact .so name where the ffdec_h264 is present, why does it give the same error of element not found. Can you tell me some debug option to dig more or what might be wrong here?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/cmake/FindGStreamer.cmake

Comment: Tried that too, no luck. Something peculiar which I will have to figure out.